# Shell scripting did not work in bamboo - how can I get latest build version

Tags: bash, shell, build, bamboo

I have a code like this which is working my local computer:

```
 __latest_version=

for dir in $(ls -1 "${RAW_BUILD_PATH}\\${release_major_version}"); do

IFS='.' read -r -a array <<< "$dir"

if [[ ${array[0]} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ ${array[1]} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then 
    if [[ "${array[0]}${array[1]}" != "${__latest_version[0]}${__latest_version[1]}" ]]; then
        __latest_version[0]="${array[0]}";
        __latest_version[1]="${array[1]}";
    fi
fi

done
```

Result should be something like this:
18.1.2.3

But when I want to run this as inline script in bamboo it doesnt work.
Errors are like:

error   04-Apr-2018 15:10:02    Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.

error   04-Apr-2018 15:10:02    Missing file specification after redirection operator.

error   04-Apr-2018 15:10:02    The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
...

Comment: How are you running this script? I see there is no shebang. Maybe a wrong interpreter is used to run the script. Besides the errors you get do not seem to originate from Bash.

Comment: Run this script with bamboo as inline script. I do not rule out that I´m mixing bash with something. Shell is kind a new for me. Maybe the main question is how to resolve this kind a thing in bash?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Can you show us the command or the configuration file you use in Bamboo, especially the part that run this script? Something like `./script.sh`?

Comment: [related issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Making-a-Bamboo-Script-execute-using-bin-bash/qaq-p/205364).

Comment: What is the content of ${RAW_BUILD_PATH}\\${release_major_version}  ?

Comment: I dont have /script.sh , I just run this same script. This example is just a little part of my code that gives me errors. I have one file that contains all my stuff and I just push "run" and get result. @Pawamoy

Comment: ${RAW_BUILD_PATH}\\${release_major_version} is just some url.
Something like that:
RAW_BUILD_PATH="${SERVER}\\blabla\\blabla\\DB_raw_builds\\blabla\\"
release_major_version="18.3"
and server is also my server url. @Joao